# jquery if blank append else update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have the below code, which is also contained in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/QnV7S/).

```
<div id="box"><div>click in the box</div></div>
<p>Click a name</p>
<ul>
    <li id="id-1">tom</li>
    <li id="id-2">jerry</li>
</ul>
<div id="result"></div>


<script>
        var id;
    var person;
    jQuery(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
        id = jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
        person = jQuery(this).text();
        $("#box").show();
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#box").click(function (e) {
            var d = new Date();
            $( "#result" ).append( "<div class='item'>" + person + " last clicked the box at " + d + "</div>");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Currently you click on a persons name, then when you click on the box it appends the persons name and the time you clicked on the box.

Instead of having this happen repeatedly I want to append the person if they haven't been clicked before and if they have I want to update there latest item with the last time they clicked the box.

I am really stuck with how I would go about doing this, something like if blank append else update?  What is the best way to handle something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the last click date as a `data` parameter on the item itself. Then you can easily tell if it has or has not been clicked. Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
    $(this).data('clickdate', new Date());
    $("#box").show();
});

$("#box").click(function (e) {
    var $box = $(this).empty();
    $('li').each(function(i, el) {
        var clickDate = $li.data('clickdate');
        var $item = $('<p />', {
            text: $(el).text() + ' : ' + (clickDate || 'Not clicked')
        });
        $box.append($item);
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/QnV7S/5/)

As you can see in the fiddle, this shows all `li` elements, even if they have not been clicked. If required, you can remove the unclicked ones by appending the append line to:

```
clickDate && $box.append($div);
```

Comment: This is great, I like how you have also added in that you can only click on the person once and you need to click on them again to register an update.  With that feature how is that working? I don;t quite understand how once you click on the box the values are reset?

Comment: The values are reset because on click of `#box` it's looping through all available `li` elements and grabbing their values. Therefore it is rebuilding all the information each time.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var cache = {},person,id;
   jQuery(document).on("click", "li", function (event) {
        id = jQuery(this).attr('id') || '';
        $(this).data('appended' , true);
        person = jQuery(this).text();
        cache[person] = true;
        $("#box").show();
    });

    $(function () {
        $("#box").click(function (e) {
            var d = new Date();
            if( cache[person] ){
             //update
            }else{
                $( "#result" ).append( "<div class='item'>" + person + " last clicked the box at " + d + "</div>");
            }
        });
    });
```

I wish  this code above  can help you

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $("#box").click(function (e) {
        var d = new Date();
        var $div = $('#result .item[data-id="' + id + '"]');
        if ($div.length == 0) {
            $div = $('<div/>', {
                "class": 'item',
                "data-id": id
            }).appendTo('#result');
        }
        $div.html(person + ' last clicked the box at ' + d);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CDCLF/)

I might have done it slightly different using a class attribute to mark the clicked item: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CDCLF/2/